# Android StartActivity option menu

Tags: android, android-intent, menu, android-activity

I'm trying to start an activity from OptionsMenu, but it doesn't start. Why?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    case R.id.main:
        Intent intent = null;
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Impostazioni.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? Did you declare Impostazioni in AndroidManifest?

Comment: Add break point or log statement in case R.id.main to see if it is actually getting hit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Delay is in milliseconds
static final int DRAWER_DELAY = 200;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

  //open navigationDrawer
  new Handler().postDelayed(openDrawerRunnable(), DRAWER_DELAY);

    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    case R.id.main:
        Intent intent = null;
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Impostazioni.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Method to open the Navigation Drawer...

```
private Runnable openDrawerRunnable() {
    return new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this way nothing happens, and you do not even open the Navigation Drawer

Comment: That code takes priority over all of the rest of the responses here.  So you return true and that's all you're going to get.  Shouldn't that call to `mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` be inside the switch under `case android.R.id.home` or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

Don't you end up returning early when you do?

```
if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
    return true;
}
```

You never reach the code for `startActivity` I think.  If that's not the case, are you sure the menu item has id `R.id.main`?  I would want to debug this code with a break point at the top of this method - then step through and see what gets called and what doesn't.